# Making an app using swift that gets user's location

Tags: ios, swift, gps

I ran my code for getting the user's location and this is the error I get. Can someone please help me figure it out?

My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var citybtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var citylbl: UILabel!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var currentLocation : CLLocation!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Used to start getting the users location
    //let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


    // For use when the app is open
    //locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    // If location services is enabled get the users location
    //if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest // You can change the locaiton accuary here.
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()



}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    locationAuthStatus()
}

func locationAuthStatus() {

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {

        currentLocation = locationManager.location
        print(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        print(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)

    } else {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationAuthStatus()
    }
}



@IBAction func buttonpresses(_ sender: Any) {

}



}
```

[image: Error that gets printed onto console]

Comment: Is this a compilation error or runtime error? Does the application run and then crashes and prints those 2 lines?

Comment: Just because you are authorised for location, doesn't mean you will have a location. You need to set the location manager delegate, call `startUpdatingLocation` and wait for a call to `updateLocations`. I don't believe the lines you have shown from the console are related to your issue.

Comment: Hey this is a run time error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you did not enable the location update capability of your target:

- choose target
- select capabilities
- in Background Modes, tick Location updates